# How can I thumbnail images in serialization of Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I recently jumped into Django REST Framework. Before using it, I thumbnailed images using [django-imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit). Like you see the models below, it worked well, so I used original size images from `image` and thumbnailed size images from `image_thumbnail`.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    image = ProcessedImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=image_path,
                                processors=[Thumbnail(1000, 1400)], format='JPEG')
    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(
        source='image', format='JPEG', options={'quality': 40})
    ...
```

The problem is I can't use `image_thumbnail` in my serializers. I can use `image`, but `image_thumbnail` throws an error message `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.`

**serializers.py**

```
class ImageRandomSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', 'image_thumbnail', )
```

Can I not thumbnailed images from models.py in serializers.py? Should I thumbnail them with some Django REST Framework thumbnail tool?

**UPDATE**

After setting DEBUG=True, it throws the error `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`.

Comment: please set the DEBUG equal to True in settings file and retry, then add original error content to your question

Comment: @M.J Shoot, didn't know it was related to DEBUG. Updated the post!

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the answer from [here](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/issues/343).

Added `image_thumbnail = ImageField(read_only=True)`, and now it's working well.

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ImageField

class ImageRandomSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    store = StoreDomainKeySerializer()
    image_thumbnail = ImageField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('store', 'image', 'image_thumbnail',)
```